# FFT with frequencies with decimal places - how to quantify that frequencies are equally weighted?

Tags: python, fft

With the code below, I want to get an overview how different frequencies are present in the input signal and which "strength" they have.

This works very well if the frequencies of the sinus waves have no decimal places (like: `5.0` and `20.0`) - see first screenshot below: I get for both frequencies a sharp peak in the fft and also the height as well as the frequency itself are equivalent to the input parameters in my code.

Unfortunately, the situation is different if a frequency has decimal places (like: `5.4` for one frequency) - see second screenshot: now the 5.4 are not a sharp peak in the fft plot anymore and also the hight of the peak is different to the amplitude of 2.0 of that sinus wave.

I have two questions:

1. What can I do regarding changing the `number of points` (`n`) or other parameters to have also for `5.4` a sharp peak with height 2.0 as in the other screenshot.
2. What is the proper mathematical way to calculate the strength of a frequency range (like 0 < x < 10) and to compare it with another range (like 20 < x < 30). My expectation is that also for a frequency of `5.4` both ranges should deliver the same `frequency strength`.

The code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, fftfreq

# setup for domain - number of points
n = 1000.

# distance (in meters) or time period (in seconds)
Lx = 100.

omega = 2.0 * np.pi / Lx
x = np.linspace(0, Lx, n)

y1 = 2.0 * np.sin(5.4 * omega * x)
y2 = 2.0 * np.sin(25.0 * omega * x)

y = y1 + y2

freqs = fftfreq(int(n))

mask = freqs >= 0

nwaves = freqs * n

fft_vals = fft(y)

# true theoretical fft
fft_theo = 2.0 * np.abs(fft_vals / n)  # multiplied by 2 because I do not look at negative frequencies and have to take their values into account here, too.

plt.figure(8)
plt.plot(nwaves[mask], fft_theo[mask], "-o", markersize=4, label='fft')
plt.xlim(-0.1, 30)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='b', linestyle='--')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='y', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot 1]:

Screenshot 1: the lower frequency is `5.0`

[image: Screenshot 2]

Screenshot 2: the lower frequency is `5.4`

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, you can use Sinc interpolation (or reconstruction) to see the actual spectrum of a windowed sinewave between strictly-integer-periodic-in-aperture frequencies.

There is no sharp peak for any finite length signal.  It only looks that way because you are only plotting integer periodic frequency points.

Comment: The missing links: [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) (see how it is zero at integer points except the center), and the concept of [windowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function)

Comment: @hotpaw2 (or others): thanks for answer. Unfortunately I am not able to benefit from it right now. Some questions still remain: 1. do you have a link to some code where a sinc interpolation is done? 2. Is the sinc interpolation done in the frequency domain? 3. After doing a sinc interpolation: am I afterwards able to judge the 'amount of signal' that prevails in a dedicated frequency range compared to another frequency range?

Comment: And regarding topic no. 1 in my previous comment: I saw that you delivered in an dsp.stackexchange.com the following link. But I have to admit that I am not able to compile the referring code from it... https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Theory_Ideal_Bandlimited_Interpolation.html

Comment: Here's some windowed-Sinc upsampling interpolation code written long ago in a dialect of Tiny Basic: http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/dsp.html#3

Comment: Thanks for that link. And will I be able to judge the 'amount of signal' that prevails in a dedicated frequency range after doing the sinc interpolation?‬